# How can I click on Launchpad and make it to behave like secondary click performed?

Tags: macos, mojave, launchpad

I dislike the big eye-candy icons that I see after clicking the Launchpad icon on the dock. However I like the menu that I see after a secondary click on Launchpad. How can I make the click/tap on the Launchpad behave like a secondary click?

Comment: Press the **control** key when clicking and it will show the context menu.

Comment: Tap with two fingers on the Launchpad icon in the Dock with Trackpad. Or right-click it with the mouse.

Comment: @user3439894 Yeah I can do that, but I just want to do with single tap.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a clean compact list of applications in your Dock, consider instead adding the `/Applications` folder to you Dock and setting it to "View as List".

[image: options for Apps folder in dock]

[image: final list of applications folder in dock]